# TortoiseSVN: Where can I view kept 'Change Lists'?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I recently discovered TortoiseSVN's ability to allow for *Change Lists* during a commit to organize files in a single commit that might not all be related to the same change/modification.  Before commiting, I made sure to check the `Keep changelists` button and I expected the changelist "tag" to show up in the `Show Log` dialog after the commit but they do not.

So my question are:

1. Where can I view the kept changelists if not in the log?
2. For what purpose does the `keep changelists` box serve if not to be able to see how one organized/tag their commit after-the-fact?

The only thing the manual has to say about the `Keep changelists` box is the following; as you can see it's pretty vague.

> If you wish to retain the file in its changelist, use the Keep
>   changelists checkbox at the bottom of the commit dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you have to read ["Changelists"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.changelists.html) chapter from SVN Book in order to understand changelist concepts in Subversion deeper and greater

In short:

- Changelists are client-only feature, not known to and not reflected by server - files in committed changelist for server is just ordinary set of files
- *If* some changelists exist in Working Copy (not committed or saved as is after commit), changelists-list and their content will be in `svn status` output
- If you have mixed-work (for *any* reasons) for more than one commit ("Commit often!"), you want to save separation during all work-time